# TeamCity: How to setup proper trigger file wildcards

Tags: teamcity, devops

Say I have a solution containing the following projects in a folder-tree (this is C# but could in principle be anything):

```
MySolution
- SharedFolderA
  - File1.cs
  - File2.cs
  - SharedProject.csproj
- SharedFolderB
  - File1.cs
  - File2.cs
  - SharedProject.csproj
- Hosts
  - Host1
    - Program.cs
    - Host1.csproj
  - Host2
    - Program.cs
    - Host2.csproj
```

Now in TeamCity I wish to make building of each host into seperate builds. So I will have a project called `MySolution` containing the following builds:

- Build Host1
- Build Host2

Now comes the question: For each build I want to setup a VCS trigger rule, that triggers the build if the commits contain changes to either

- files in the root folder
- files in one or more of the shared folders
- files in the specific host folder - *but not the other host folder*

Example: Build of Host2 should trigger if any files have been changed in any of the following folders:

- MySolution
- SharedFolderA
- SharedFolderB
- Hosts/Host2

**How should I setup the File wildcards?**

Answer (score 0):

The format is as follows from TeamCity [Ref](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+VCS+Triggers) *Perhaps consider a different approach, since you have different build/host conditions!*

---

**Option 1:**

##### Since you have various hosts with build conditions, a dependency build with wildcards is (IMHO) **recommended, i.e. use the Artifact Dependency feature which in turn allows wild cards in files & folders picture below.

[image: Team City Maven Wildcard Build Artifact Dependency]

---

Option 2: However if you choose to go down your *original* Build Trigger Path, you can try this.

> `+|-[:user=VCS_username;]root=VCS_root_id;]comment=VCS_comment_regexp]]:Ant_like_wildcard`

[image: Trigger Rules]

Once you have setup via the UI, you can make a copy and edit the triggers by adding modifying like so.

```
//all files, or .CS in the root folder
/root/**
/root/*.cs

//files in one or more of the shared folders
/root/SharedFolderA/**
/root/SharedFolderB/*.cs

//files in the specific host folder - but not the other host folder
/root/SharedFolderA/**
// the -ve sign will ignore it
-/root/Hosts/Host2/**
```

You can add regex or `**` or `?` singmatch

[image: Sample Trigger Configuration]

---